# how to set classpath to logger

Tags: java, logging, log4j

i work with log4j and now that i want to use it i get this:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (xmlModul.XmlLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

but the website didnt help me and i asked this some time ago but i simply cant figure out how and where to set the class path.

but now that the deadline draws near i'm frightened that i cant finish it.

I really need a step-by-step solution.

thank you for your help.

Edit:

i know that the file has to be in the directory but no matter where i put it it wont find the log4j.properties file

Comment: is the problem you don't know what is meant by classpath?

Comment: i know that the file has to be in the directory but no matter where i put it it wont find the log4j.properties file